# Invoke remote MSBuild script inside a MSBuild script with cygwin sshd

Tags: msbuild, cygwin, openssh

I'm trying to do some MSBuild automation for deploy and backup. I tried several different remote execution platforms (Powershell/WMI, PsExec and Cygwin) and had some troubles with all of them.

With Powershell and PsExec, I think the problem is some security baselines used on the machines. I don't have full control of the machines and domain.

The most stable scenario I found is with cygwin/openssh. But when I'm running plink inside MSBuild and trying to invoke MSBuild remotely, msbuild hangs without telling me the error. If I run directly plink from prompt, everything works fine.

The MSBuild script follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">   
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Plink>"c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe"</Plink>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Password></Password>
        <HostName>localhost</HostName>
        <RemoteCommand2>/cygdrive/c/SandBox/remotemsbuild/echoalotoffiles.bat</RemoteCommand2>      
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">       
        <Exec Command="$(Plink) -l $(UserName) -pw $(Password) -batch $(HostName) $(RemoteCommand2)" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="EchoALotOfFiles">
        <ItemGroup>
            <SandBoxFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\**\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Message Text="@(SandBoxFiles)" />
    </Target>
 </Project>
```

When I run the first target, Build, I have the issue (MSBuild hanging)

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 02/11/2013 12:01:45.
Project "C:\SandBox\remotemsbuild\remotemsbuild.build" on node 1 (EchoALotOfF
iles target(s)).
EchoALotOfFiles:
```

If I run just plink from command line, everything works fine.

Any guesses?

Comment: just tried this with a default cygwin sshd setup, and I cannot reproduce the problem. First ran plink on the command line to login and make sure the key is cached, then from msbuild ran `Command="/path/to/plink -l <user> -p <pw> -batch localhost ls` and it properly lists all files in my home directory. Can you check if basic command like ls etc work, and also what happens when msbuild hangs? Is the plink process still running at that point?

Comment: The flow is: MSBuild local -> plink -> MSBuild remote... did you try this example?

Comment: Yes tried that as well, works ok. I didn't have lots of files to list though, maybe you're hitting a limit there? Can you get a simple Message task to work? What exactly is in your echoalotoffiles.bat ?

Comment: Thank you for the interest in the problem. I'll redo my sample to give more feedback (this question is here since Nov'13)

Comment: didn't even notice that.. well, the older an unanswered yet still relevant question is, the more it deserves an answer :]

Comment: Shame on me. I did again the tests and it's working! I don't know if it is an environment issue since I'm testing on a different environment or if redoing the tests I fixed something. :-(. I'll redo in my other machine to make sure I isolated the bug (if it exists!)